# What are the Aura committee digests in headers used for?

Tags: aura, light-client, digest

Aura (as well as Grandpa and Babe, but I'm currently only interested in Aura) includes the whole authority set in the header digest when it changes, as well as additional information about authorities being disabled. As far as I know, light clients are the main targets of this information, as they can use it to verify quite long chains of headers without needing to download entire blocks, but are there any other known uses?

Some additional context: we would like headers to have fixed size, independent of the size of the committee. To this end we want to replace these digests with hashes of the committees and eventually write our own implementations of light clients which will download the committee contents out-of-band and only verify them using the hashes in headers. Before we fully commit to that we would like to know whether/which other tools might be broken by such a change.